# Airbrake notification not send from iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, airbrake

I am using airbrake in iOS but I am not getting any crash notification in my paid airbrake account. I have implemented as explained in the airbrake iOS git here
https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ios

This is code in Objective-c I have written in app delegate as follows

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [ABNotifier startNotifierWithAPIKey:@"xxxx"
                              projectID:@"xxxxxx"
                        environmentName:ABNotifierAutomaticEnvironment
                                 useSSL:YES // only if your account supports it
                               delegate:(id)self];
    return YES;
}
```

and also in ViewController where the app crashes. The code is

```
- (IBAction)crashBttnAction:(id)sender {
        NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [arr objectAtIndex:5];
}
```

The app is crashing forcefully but I do not get any notification in my airbrake paid account.This is the link to my test github project

https://github.com/vikashbitcanny/AirBrakeIOSTest

Comment: Did you contact their support?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.
I downloaded your code and tried my own account with airbrake key, project id and app bundle id. 
So it maybe something related to the project setup